# How to model two to-many relationships in Core Data?

Tags: ios, core-data

I'm working with a business model that includes flights, passengers and service requests.

A flight has passengers. A passenger has zero to many service requests.

I need to display a view showing all passengers having service requests on a flight, grouped by service request type. Passengers will appear once within each group for which they have a service request.

The data for the view needs to come from Core Data.

My question is how to model the relationship in Core Data in a way that makes it efficient to retrieve the data for my view, and how to write an efficient fetch request.

I am proceeding with creating the Core Data entities like this:

Flight --- to many ---> Passenger --- to many ---> Service Request

But I am wondering if this is efficient. Would a different (denormalized) model make more sense:

Flight --- to many ---> Service Request

Where each service request would include the passenger name. Thanks for any advice you can give.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it will have better performance to use **denormalized** model to retrieve the data.


And you can use **predicate** to decide whether to or not to add the new objects in Service Request (include the passenger names) list.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I will consider this.

Answer (score 0):

I would start by clarifying the relationship between `Flights` and `Passengers`: a `Flight` has many `Passengers`, but can a `Passenger` be on many `Flights`?  If that relationship is indeed many-many, then I think you should add an intermediate entity (a `Journey`, say):

```
Flight <---->> Journey <<----> Passenger
```

Each Journey represents a single Passenger on a single Flight (and indeed might have some attributes, such as SeatNumber).  A ServiceRequest would then be related to a single Journey, but there could be many ServiceRequests for a single Journey:

```
Journey <---->> ServiceRequest
```

If you are planning to use an `NSFetchedResultsController` to build your table view, then you could use `ServiceRequest` as the entity for the fetch, with a predicate based on `ServiceRequest.Journey.Flight` to filter the results to a particular flight, grouped using `ServiceRequestType` as the `sectionNameKeyPath`.  You would then have to use `ServiceRequest.Journey.Passenger` to access the passenger's details for display.  There will be some overhead in traversing these relationships to get the Flight and Passenger details, but you can use pre-fetching to minimise the impact.

As regards your second option, how would you model those Passengers who have no Service Requests?

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. In this app the passengers are only associated with one flight. For purposes of displaying the service requests, the view only needs to display passengers with requests. The complication comes when we need to display other passenger info on other views; this would suggest a normalized model but I wondered about performance. I'm working on it now and will see how it goes.

Answer (score 0):

Based on my experience I think these models in a question of performance are equal.
As the data's volume which will be connected to flight in both cases are relatively equal.

Model 1:

- min passengers = 0 (empty flight)
- max passengers = max plane capacity
  ( let it be 2000)

Model 0

- min services request = 0 (greedy people)
- max services request =
  passengers x 2 (lucky flight)

If you in doubt it is possible to add the relation from the second model to the first model

```
Flight ---to many---> Passenger ---to many---> Service Request --to one-> Flight
```